# I can't load my chrome profile in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir= C:/Users/soham/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" , options=options)
```

This is my code.
I tried everything but it keeps giving me this error:

(most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 12, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in **init**
RemoteWebDriver.**init**(
File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\soham\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

Comment: Post the full error code, this is just half the error I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:/Users/soham/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/
```

path is missing the goal folder.
In order to import your default Chrome profile you should use this:

```
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir= C:/Users/soham/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")
```

In order to import any other Chrome profile you should mention that profile folder similarly.

Comment: ohh actually i found the answer... it happened due to the space in the equal to sign and the path `--user-data-dir= C:/Users/soham/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/`